# Adding 3rd party controls to .NET Core WPF application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, controls

Section **Controls, NuGet Packages, and Existing Assembly References** of .NET Core 3 release notes on [Support for Windows Desktop Applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/) states the following:

> Desktop applications often have many dependencies, maybe from a
>   control vendor, from NuGet or binaries that don’t have source any
>   more. It’s not like all of that can be updated to .NET Core 3 quickly
>   or maybe not even at all.
>
> As stated above, we intend to support dependencies as-is. If you are
>   at the Build conference, you will see Scott Hunter demo a .NET Core 3
>   desktop application that uses an existing 3rd-party control. We will
>   continue testing scenarios like that to validate .NET Core 3
>   compatibility.

I created a WPF application targeting .NET Core 3 in VS 2019 using `dotnet new wpf` command, and it works fine.

However, when I add a 3rd party WPF control from NuGet (control was built targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1) I get the following error message:

> Warning   NU1701  Package 'Syncfusion.Shared.WPF 16.4.0.52' was restored
>   using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target
>   framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully
>   compatible with your project.

The application still builds successfully but when I attempt to run the application `public MainWindow()` throws :

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''The invocation of the
>   constructor on type 'Syncfusion.Windows.Tools.Controls.GroupBar' that
>   matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line
>   number '16' and line position '10'.'

Was anyone able to add a reference to a 3rd party WPF control to a WPF application targeting .NET Core 3 and if so what is the trick?

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/4272/support-for-net-core-3 Then you have to wait.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the link but according to Microsoft the existing 3rd party controls should work with .NET Core WPF apps... I'm hoping there is a way to make that happen and that someone already did it...

Comment: It says the Syncfusion controls threw an exception, you'd need to dig into what exactly it tried to do.. Please consider filing an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/wpf. They need this kind of reports to work on compatibility.

Comment: You can't just reference any .NET Framework assembly from a .NET Core app and expect it to work as-is. Did you try to run the [portability analyzer tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/08/08/are-your-windows-forms-and-wpf-applications-ready-for-net-core-3-0/) to see if the app is compatible?

Comment: @mm8 "As stated above, we intend to support dependencies as-is. If you are at the Build conference, you will see Scott Hunter demo a .NET Core 3 desktop application that uses an existing 3rd-party control. "

Comment: @MartinUllrich, Thanks for the advice, will submit a report...

Comment: Obviously any code that depends on an API that is not available in .NET Core won't work when running on .NET Core.

Comment: @mm8 Again, that is not what Microsoft is saying...